# How can I remove mold from my walls?

Tags: walls, painting, mold

I'm trying to paint this wall but as you can see, there are mold on it.  What would be the best way to remove the mold on my walls?

[image]

Comment: Is this inside or outside? Is it in a living space or in a basement or a storeroom?

Comment: hi @JimStewart it is in a kitchen. The mold happens just below a window, close to the washing machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend if the mold is only on the surface and why it's growing there. You'll just run in to the same situation again and again.

If it's because of humid room air, like a bathroom, you should ensure the room has better ventilation. Get a better fan or install one if it doesn't exist.

If it's because of improper wall construction, no insulation, no vapor barrier, etc. Then you'll need to correct that.

All else good, use bleach and water to kill the mold and a fan to ventilate the room (because it will be toxic). Final wash with a sponge and soap and water, let dry, paint with a good sealer primer, then paint with a bathroom type paint.

Answer (score 2):

Soap and water with a rag or scrubby brush while wearing a mask.

I was at Home Depot yesterday and noticed a number of products for cleaning, killing, protecting from mold growth that I never saw before. I don't know if they're any better than soap and water and just keeping the area dry.

Answer (score 2):

I think a mildewcide is absolutely necessary. Soap and water will in general not kill the mold if the wall is at all porous. What is the material of this wall: drywall, plaster, or concrete?

If this is drywall and the mold has penetrated deeply into the wall, the best procedure might be to replace the drywall. If this is concrete, then it should be possible to use a mildew killer, dry the wall, then prime and paint.

Did the wall get wet from the side we are viewing or from the other side?