# How can I get rid of this mold prior to new paint job?

Tags: mold, repainting

I am about to repaint a flat that is close to the sea, not very ventilated hence a bad case of mold developing. What is most concerning is that the outside of the condo has been fully done up recently (i.e cracks repaired, new waterproof painting etc.).

My plan is:

1. cleaning the apartment interior walls with bleach and /or vinegar
2. applying a good primer to the walls
3. painting with anti-fungi paint

Any recommendations and or changes what you'd guys use ? thanks so much for sharing your experiences? All the best !

[image]

Comment: bleach and vinegar do not mix

Comment: Shouldn't you target ventilation or leaks first?

Comment: Or this? [How can I remove mold from my walls?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/120170/how-to-remove-mold-on-wall)

Answer (score 2):

Bleach. Not vinegar, not mold remover, not ammonia. Bleach. Apply with a sprayer. Wait 5 minutes. Scrub. Hose down. If the paint is in good shape, no primer needed. Just add fungicide to the new paint. If the moisture conditions remain, the mold will eventually return. But cleaning and scrubbing is almost always cheaper than fixing ventilation/humidity issues.

Comment: I want to upvote this but... As your answer of bleach is correct...

But tyou then go on to say "cleaning scrubbing is almost always cheaper than fixing ventilation/humidity issues"... Thats true, it is cheaper... But it is much cheaper to fix ventilation/humidity issues then to deal with stuff behind the walls that you cannot clean that are also busy molding and rotting.

Comment: tldr: mold on the surface of a wall means there is a high chance that the stuff behind the drywall is also molding/rotting.

Comment: The mold in the picture is typical surface black mold. When the moisture comes from beneath the drywall, the pattern and color are totally different. I live in an area with high humidity and mold is a constant problem. I clean surfaces with bleach every year. The Sheetrock and framing are in perfect shape.

Comment: Whether or not the mould is rooted in the subsurface, it’s concerning that it has come back after a recent paint job. If it is not subsurface, then the way to avoid constant cleaning and repainting will be to achieve some air circulation. Trickle vents may help if not already in place. I’d clean, and wait before deciding whether it is solved, and then repaint afterwards.

Comment: I'm not there, but I bet there's probably nothing wrong with the house. Hot humid air touching a colder surface will precipitate, and mold will grow on any wet surface. The mold is not coming from below, but from air spores. You can test this by leaving a piece of wood leaning against the wall, and you'll see mold growing on it. In some environments, cleaning mold is part of normal house maintenance